# Does SharePoint Online still extract metadata from photos loaded into Asset Library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, metadata, asset-library

I have a number of Drone photos that I would like to make searchable from SharePoint.

In SharePoint 2013, if you upload photos into an asset library, the metadata is extracted and entered into a column provided the column exists (and is named properly).

This feature doesn't seem to work in SharePoint Online.

Does anyone have any insight on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Martin, what metadata property are you using? Something like "Comments" and "Tags"? I've never heard of photos to carry over metadata to SharePoint when you upload them to  an Assets Library. I've just tried it out of curiousity and it didn't work. Maybe it was Word documents? I'm super curious what made this feature work for you in the past.

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov you are not seeing them cause you are not creating an Asset Library with those columns.  Here is the article: https://spjohnadams.wordpress.com/2012/10/24/how-to-extract-exif-meta-data-from-photographs-automatically-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: How interesting, I had no idea about this feature. In any case, it does not seem to work. I've populated "Copyright" property for the picture and uploaded it to Site Assets where "wic_System_Copyright" field was already there. Sadly, nothing happened. I've also tried SharePoint Migration tool. It also does not migrate these properties.

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov That is odd.  What version of SharePoint are you using?  In my case I checked that the photos had data in them...such last Latitude.  I then created a text column called....wic_System_GPS_Latitude and dragged the photos in from Windows explorer.  I think uploading using the menu didn't work, if memory serves.

Comment: @MartinMuldoon I think this might be because Microsoft focus has been on Document library rather than any other apps.  However, you could try creating a Picture Library and show/hide the columns like 'MediaServiceAutoTags' & 'MediaServiceLocation'.  You will see the images are being tagged automatically.  If this doesn't meet your requirement you could use Flow and Cognitive Services to tag

Comment: @SharePointer I created a Picture Library in SharePoint Online.  I'm not seeing the columns that you are referencing...MediaServiceAutoTags for example.  Am I missing something?

Comment: By default it won't show you these columns so if you click the column setting from the view and 'Show/Hide columns' you can make them available on the view.

Comment: @SharePointer I'm in Settings on my Picture Library.  I don't see that setting.  I go into the default view, and it's not there either.

Comment: It won't be in the Settings.  You will need to use the the down arrow next to a column in the picture library and click 'Column setting' >> 'Show/hide columns.  This will open a panel on the right where you will see all the columns.